# Hibernate Search Annotations not Inherited

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I am indexing a class whose superclass has the following annotations:

```
@Indexed
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
```

The same @Inheritance annotation is on the subclass.  The annotations of the superclass are all on methods.  The field I want indexed on the superclass is ignored:

```
@Field(index=Index.UN_TOKENIZED,store=Store.YES)
@FieldBridge(impl=org.hibernate.search.bridge.builtin.BooleanBridge.class)
@Type(type="yes_no")
public boolean isFlagged() {
    return flagged;
}
```

The superclass only has the flagged property and the ID.  The ID shows up fine, because it has the @Id annotation, but I'm not sure why flagged is not indexed.  I found [this post](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HSEARCH-249?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel) but it doesn't give a clear answer.  What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the @Indexed annotation also on the subclass? You should.
It would probably help if you post the fully annotated super- and sub-class code.
The @FieldBridge annotation on isFlagged is unnecessary. BooleanBridge is the default.

BTW, you might have more luck with this question on the [Hibernate Search Forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewforum.php?f=9).

--Hardy

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  @Indexed is on both super and sub classes.  I'll see if I can get a small sample and post it.